# Firebase Authentication not working with React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple app using React and Firebase (Cloud Firestore & Authentication).
I have used Firebase Authentication Sign in/ sign up with email and password but the promises have no response, although it worked well last night, and firebase.auth().onStateAuthChanged is not working neither but firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail() works well. I do not know what is wrong?

You can check my code at: https://lfddm.csb.app/ (I've used codesandbox)

The firebase cloud firestore rules:

```
match /users/{userId} {
    allow create: if request.auth.uid != null
  allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId
}
```

The SignIn component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input
} from "reactstrap";

import firebase from "../config/firebase";

export default function SignInModal(props) {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const resetModal = () => {
    setModal(false);
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
  };

  const signIn = (e, p) => {
    // console.log(e, p);
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(e, p)
      .then(() => alert("Sign in successfully!"))
      .then(() => resetModal())
      .catch(err => alert(err.message));
  };

  const styles = {
    signModal: {
      display: "inline",
      margin: "0 3px"
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="SignModal" style={styles.signModal}>
      <Button color="primary" onClick={() => setModal(!modal)}>
        Sign In
      </Button>
      <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={() => resetModal()}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={() => resetModal()}>Sign In</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <Form
            onSubmit={e => {
              e.preventDefault();
              signIn(email, password);
            }}
          >
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="email">Email</Label>
              <Input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="password">Password</Label>
              <Input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                value={password}
                onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                required
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              color="primary"
              style={{ marginRight: "5px" }}
            >
              Sign In
            </Button>
            <Link to="/forget-password">Forget password</Link>
          </Form>
        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

signIn function does not return anything, it means that the firebase.auth() promise is pending.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what 'promises have no response' means and include some of that code as well?

Comment: Could you also include the expected response vs actual response? It's a bit difficult to properly diagnose this issue with minimal information. I would suggest providing as much information as you can in your post.

Comment: @Saccarab I editted the post, thank you for your advice

Comment: @JKleinne  I editted the post, thank you for your advice

Comment: Check if you have a remote debugger open in your browser to see if it's interfering with the application. Furthermore, if you believe this to be a bug on Firebase's side, as denoted by the fact that it worked well last night and suddenly stopped working today, you can open a ticket with [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact/) to help you resolve this issue.